# if statement is nt working in android code

Tags: android

ok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

```
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(mode.getText().toString()=="Default"){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Cannot Delete Default", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }


            //else{

            /*  db = openOrCreateDatabase("MY_App_Data", MODE_PRIVATE, null);

            db.execSQL(DATABASE_TABLE_CREATE);
            ContentValues cvInsert=new ContentValues();
            cvInsert.put("mode",mode.getText().toString());
            cvInsert.put("msg",msg.getText().toString());
            db.insert("SSP_Data", null, cvInsert);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Mode Added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            list.add(mode.getText().toString());*/
            //}
        }
    });
```

hey guys in the above code my if statement is not working please help me out there iz no syntax error then why its nt executing please say smthing abt it

Comment: You should read about java before getting into android, mode.getText().toString()=="Default" is looking if strings are pointing at same string object, mode.getText().toString().equals("Default") is what you might need...

Answer (score 2):

You can't compare `String`s this way in Java. Use .`equals()`

```
if("Default".equals(mode.getText().toString()){
```

Using `==` checks if they are the same `Object` but not if they have the same values.

Also, putting the `String` in front of the variable this way protects against a `NPE`. Your `mode.getText().toString()` could `return null` but your literal `String` will not.

Answer (score 0):

Use `.equals` or `.equalsIgnoreCase` to compare strings

```
if(mode.getText().toString().equals("Default")){
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use equals to compare strings, like this:

```
if(mode.getText().toString().equals("Default")){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Cannot Delete Default", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't say how it didn't work, but you almost certainly wanted this:

```
if (mode.getText().toString().equals("Default"))
```

rather than this:

```
if (mode.getText().toString() == "Default")
```

The first tests to see whether the two strings have the same content. The second tests to see if they're the *same* string.